# Derivation of Critical Mass of U-235

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I am having trouble following an explanation of the critical mass of U-235 from my book (for high school physics). First off, every chain reaction of U-235 releases on average $\nu = 2.42$ neutrons. Then, it defines the mean free path to be $\ell = \frac{1}{n\sigma}$, with $n$ being the denisty of uranium atoms and $\sigma$ the cross section of the reaction (what is the heuristic for this being the average length traveled before a collision?). This means that the number of non-interacting neutrons as a function of the distance traveled $x$, is $N(x)=N_0e^{-n\sigma x}$, provided no new neutrons are produced.

Then it says - and this is one of the things I don't understand - the condition for an explosion i.e. a self-sustaining chain reaction, is that atleast one of the $\nu = 2.42$ neutrons released begins a new reaction:

\begin{align}
\nu e^{-\frac{R}{\ell}} < \nu-1, 
\end{align}
with $R$ being the size of the uranium clump (where does the inequlity come from and why is that the precise mathematical relationship to encapsulate the condition?). Taking logs of this we obtain also $\frac{R}{\ln(\frac{\nu}{\nu-1})}>\ell$. Then we finally have that 
\begin{align}
\ell=\frac{1}{\sigma n}< \frac{R}{\ln(\frac{\nu}{\nu-1})}
\end{align}

Assuming the uranium is spherical with density $\rho$, the mass is 
\begin{align}
M=\rho \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 = \frac{4}{3}\pi\frac{\rho}{\sigma^3n^3}\left(\ln\left(\frac{\nu}{\nu-1}\right)\right)^3.
\end{align}

This expression comes from solving for $R$ in the inequality above, but why do we suddenly use $=$ instead? Lastly, plugging in the relevant physical data for U-235 yields a critical mass of $\approx 43 \text{kg}$. This is a simplified approach, and a more precise one would account for the elastic collisions that slow the netron which increases the cross section, and also changes its direction, but it's this simple approach I don't really understand.

Apperciate any clarifying comments and help!

Comment: Above the critical mass, the number of neutrons will increase with time. Below it, it will decrease. The critical mass is the boundary in between. It's the mass at which the number of neutrons stays constant as a function of time. Those that disappear are matched by those that are newly created. ... Sometimes, the mathematical expressions use $=$ because they talk about conditions when things are equal - e.g. exactly the critical (border) mass. Sometimes they use $<>$ because they talk about situations above/below  the critical mass. It seems you can only be asking these trivialities.